# Turning on screen, flickering.. with logcats

Tags: root-access, 5.1-lollipop, screen-brightness

Flickering is only noticeable in 10/255 and above brightness, in 255 brightness the flickering is extreme and it only occurs in the bottom part of screen(almost the size of keyboard)... So whenever I turn off the screen then touch the screen multiple times then turn the screen on again there will be flickering. It also happens sometimes  if I plug the charger while screen is off.btw im rooted but this flickering was here since before i rooted. I tested lots of things like disabling almost all system apps and it was still there.

This live logcats are screenshotted right after turning on the screen so flickering occurs when it was created. I also noticed that flickering can only be seen when there is a layer of darkness created in the screen such as pulling the status bar, the home screen, and in the toast notification(just the whole bar of the toast notfcation)

So what exactly causes the flickering according to the logcats? amy clues on how to fix it?

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6cwi1mZj5KEUnNER1hQeW9jVVk

Comment: sorry it's a 5.1.1 version and not 5.1

Comment: uhmm can someone help ?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I really dont understand what you're asking here. Please see How to ask section in hep centre

Comment: ah sorry. my question is what exactly causes it to flicker according to the logcats? and what might be the fix for it? tnx for responding

Answer (score 0):

The symptoms you describe sound much more likely to be a hardware problem than a software problem. You probably need to get the backlight of the screen replaced (or the whole screen, if it's an OLED screen).

You shouldn't have rooted your phone when it had an existing problem, if it was still under warranty. As things are, you'll need to pay to get your phone repaired. Take it to your local phone repair shop.